Is there a way to parse multiple case classes from a join
I have the following case classes representing entities:
case class A(id: Long, name: String)

case class B(id: Long, someField: String)

val parser = Macro.namedParser[A] ~ Macro.namedParser[B]

val list = SQL"SELECT a.*, b.* FROM A as a LEFT JOIN B as b on a.id = b.a_id".as(parser.*)

The id field of A and B are identical, even though the values, of course, are not identical in the database. It seem that the parser uses the last matching column name.
How would you parse rows from a JOIN with multiple column names that clashes? The field id is probably not the only name clash in real projects.

import anorm.SqlParser.get

case class A(id: Long, name: String)
case class B(id: Long, someField: String)

// Aliasing columns to avoid clashes
val aParser: RowParser[A] = Macro.namedParser[A](
  "id" -> "a_id",
  "name" -> "a_name"
)

val bParser: RowParser[B] = Macro.namedParser[B](
  "id" -> "b_id",
  "someField" -> "b_someField"
)

val parser = aParser ~ bParser

val list = SQL"""
  SELECT 
    a.id as a_id, a.name as a_name, 
    b.id as b_id, b.someField as b_someField 
  FROM A as a 
  LEFT JOIN B as b on a.id = b.a_id
""".as(parser.*) 

Can you try this ?
